# Laravel htaccess issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I'm trying to set a site live. The site works perfectly fine on a live dev server which we've been using to show the site to the client. Here is the htaccess from the live dev (works fine):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Rewrite to 'public' folder
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^livedev.domain.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "dev16"
AuthUserFile "/home/site/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user
```

And here's the .htaccess from the live site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Rewrite to 'public' folder
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^livesite.co.uk$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The 2 are identical except for the HTTP_HOST and the removal of the authentication.

It gives me a generic "Internal Server Error".

I have tried deleting the contents of .htaccess which just gives me page not found so the issue definitely lies in .htaccess.

A total .htaccess virgin, what steps can I take to find the cause of the issue?

Thanks

(It's Laravel 3.2.13)

Comment: `Options +FollowSymlinks` requires `AllowOverride` set to `Options` or above privilege. remove that line then tell us what's going.

Comment: When I remove that line I just get a 404

Comment: That's better. It's 96 less then the previous!! check apache error log and see which file were mapped.

Comment: With the SymLinks line commented out, I'm getting "Directory index forbidden by Options directive:" in the error logs

Comment: Don't you have a `index.php` there?

Comment: To update, I was unable to get to the bottom of this and with time constraints had to repoint the DNS to the livedev environment as this was working. Will investigate further time permitting

Comment: did you try firing up livesite.co.uk/public and see if that's actually working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use at same level of /public**

This way first redirect to public

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

**And inside /public**

then, you handle index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Adding a slash before index.php worked for me. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Can you also add forcing of HTTPS to your solution please?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same setup as [RamiroRS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116678/1296104), but still got Internal Server Error. My problem was in file permissions. Folders should be 0755 and files 0644.