# Laravel 4 Internal Server Error 500 on Hostgator

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, internal-server-error

I have a Laravel 4 app deployed on shared Hostgator server.

When I navigate to:

```
http://mydomain.com/laravel/public/
```

I can see the Laravel splash screen.

but when I try to access any other route to, say, /users or /posts I am getting

```
Internal Server Error 500

http://mydomain.com/laravel/public/posts
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = $this->post->all();

        return View::make('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }
```

In Routes.php:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

I use Jeffrey Way's Generator to scaffold the posts entity.

The same works fine on my local machine. Controllers don't contain any logic, they only output the fetched data.

Error logs are empty.

Any ideas what to check? .htaccess, maybe?
Here is what I have there:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 500 errors with no server log could definitely be .htaccess. It could also be missing php extensions such as PDO or mcrypt (less likely this as usually only hidden If the php suppresses errors - I don't think Laravel does that). Try adding in the index.php file to the URL, and removing your htaccess file to test if the htaccess file is the issue.

Comment: You are right @fideloper, removing everything from .htaccess except the directive to use PHP 5.3 makes the app work:
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php

Of course, the URLs now must include index.php
In my case: mydomain.com/laravel/public/index.php/posts

So now that I know that .htaccess is causing the issue, can anyone suggest a fix for it?

Comment: I have found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16116678/385402

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in comments, a 500 error without a corresponding log file entry from the application logger is likely an .htaccess file issue.

Since the OP found the issue is related to the rewrite (and not the directive to use php 5.3):

Since this is probably a common issue on Hostgator, you should check with their help docs.

However, my first stab at a fix would be to add a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive:

```
RewriteBase /
```

So it would look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that this assumes you're running the web application form the web root and not a sub-directory.

Comment: And what if it is in a sub-directory like: public_html/domain.com/laravel ? If you have used this before it would be super-helpful if you know what the RewriteBase directive should be on top of your mind.

Comment: `RewriteBase /laravel` - Basically, whatever the subfolder is. If you access the site via "example.com/laravel" then `RewriteBase /laravel`. If you access it via "example.com/some/folders/laravel" then `RewriteBase /some/folders/laravel`.

Comment: That has worked for me, as I wasn't authorizing `AllowOverride All` in my `vhost` file. That blocked the rewrite inside of the `htaccess` file.

Comment: I have found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16116678/385402 . Thanks everyone

Comment: Had the same issue on Rackspace Cloudsites and `RewriteBase /` fixed it.

Comment: RewriteBase / also was the solution to my L4 Internal Server Error. Thank you.