# Route not loading any views

Tags: php, laravel-4

So I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to create a pretty simple route but it seems to be failing to return a view.

You can see me route below

```
Route::get('overview', function()
{
      return View::make('overview');
});
```

When a user navigates to the url: http://www.myapp.com/overview I would like the app return the overview.php page. The app right now just throws a 500 error.

My other route works perfectly so I'm confused on what exactly is going wrong. You can see it below.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
     return View::make('index');
});
```

If I change the overview route to the view index it gives me the same 500 error. index.php and overview.php are both present in the views folder.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Showing the test page which fails to load. The page named test.php and can be found in app/views If I change the overview route to `View::make('test')` it fails also.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
    <style>
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);

    body {
        margin:0;
        font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
        color: #999;
    }

    .welcome {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }

    a, a:visited {
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 32px;
        margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="welcome">
        <a href="http://laravel.com" title="Laravel PHP Framework"></a>
        <h1>You have arrived.</h1>
        </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

EDIT 2: Added my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /falke/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using `blade` template in views ? what is the path for your views and what your views contain ?

Comment: I am not using any blade templates in the views. The path to my views is /app/views My views contain html and some javascript.

Comment: Show a view for which `Laravel` throws an error.

Comment: Added a view in my edit above

Comment: It's always a good idea to check logs. The laravel.log file can be found under /app/storage/logs and may help shed some light on the issue your facing. Can you show us any info from it?

Comment: The logs folder is empty. Might it be an htaccess issue?

Comment: Sounds likely. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946186/laravel-htaccess-issue/16116678#16116678) question. Edit: also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293942/laravel-4-internal-server-error-500-on-hostgator) for info.

Comment: Added my htaccess code to the original post.

Comment: @Hassan thanks for the assist the second link fixed it. I to change RewriteBase /falke/ to RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `blade` style view loading but you are not using any blade layout and neither any blade view with `blade` in extension name. So, at first you need to use a layout for your template and it is probably available in `view/layouts/master` folder and if not then create one like:

```
// "app/views/layouts/master.blade.php"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
        <style>
            @import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700");
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

Then create your `overview.blade.php` view like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
@stop
```

So you can use in your function something like this:

```
return View::make('overview');
```

Otherwise (if not `blade`, `overview.php`) you have to use something like following in your function instead of `return View(...)`:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('overview');
```

Also for this to work, you need to use this in your `BaseController`:

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master'; // default
```

Read more on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/templates).

Comment: Still receiving the 500 internal server error after adding the quotes.

Comment: Don't think that this is the issue, as the default hello.php view with laravel uses the line without quotes.